# how to set ufw in my computer inorder to make my computer server in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, ufw, port-forwarding

how to set ufw in my computer inorder to make my computer server in lubuntu and how to portforward in ufw  i am using apache as server it is not working with public ip address i tried a lot to open ports and ports are not opening i make my ip address with wifi wlp3s0

```
sudo ufw allow in on wlp3s0 to any port 80
```

and when i use ifconfig it came like this

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:25:9f:48:f0  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:fc600000-fc620000 

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:170176 (170.1 KB)  TX bytes:170176 (170.1 KB)

   wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:6b:c3:68:80  
      inet addr:192.168.0.120  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::edfd:b52f:835c:ecd4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:55892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:45661 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:30953048 (30.9 MB)  TX bytes:7073333 (7.0 MB)
```

its not working what ever i did in ufw

Comment: Port Forwarding is something you usually do on your router, not on your Ubuntu system. The only times you need to forward ports on your Ubuntu System are: 1) You are using NAT networking for a Virtual Machine or Container, or 2) You are using an unusual port number (not 80).

Comment: ok tell me what to do in order to make my server work with public ip address @user535733

Comment: Is your server local? Or is your server someplace in the cloud (remote to you)?

Comment: local and i want to use it some where in internet as website @user535733

Comment: When you connect to your server ON YOUR LAN (like from your Phone on the same local network), does the server work?

Comment: its working but its not working with public ip address @user535733

Comment: Then your Ubuntu system is working properly. Stop trying to change your Ubuntu system. Login to your ROUTER (not your Ubuntu system), and set up port forwarding on your router. Your Public IP address is your router's address, You need to tell your router to forward Port 80 to your Server's local IP address on your LAN. That's what "Port Forwarding" is.

Comment: i done that too its not working when i used nmap  its showing no ports are open @user535733

Comment: If you set up Port Forwarding on your router properly, then ask your ISP if they block Port 80. Some do. However, this seems like basic network troubleshooting tht has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You demonstrated that your Ubuntu server is set up properly and is not the problem.

Comment: ok thank you to this